# HTML form in Adobe Animate CC

Tags: adobe, adobe-edge, animate-cc

How to insert a HTML form to a website designed using Adobe Edge Animate CC. Is there any simple way to implement ?

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your code on the stage when clicking on the {} brackets.
Inserting code like so:

```
sym.$('input_box_username').html("<input type='text' id='input_box_username' placeholder='Username'" + " maxlength='60' " + " style='background-color:white; border:1px solid #0B76d1; padding-left: 5px; width:550px; height:26px; font-size:14px;'>")

sym.$('input_box_password').html("<input type='password' id='input_box_password' placeholder='Password'" + " maxlength='40' " + " style='background-color:white; border:1px solid #0B76d1; padding-left: 5px; width:550px; height:26px; font-size:14px;'>")
```

This example will generate two input field one for a username and one for a password.
The rest of your html code can inserted like so.

Answer (score 0):

In animate in your javascript action-windows, you can refer to a form and the input fields in it - and later (after you have published your animation) you can add this form to your html - next to your canvas, or overlapping it.